# Problem with the final result of the inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am trying to solve the inequality:

$$\frac{\log(1+x^3)}{2x-\sqrt{4x+3}} \geq 0$$

I tried to find the domain for $x$:

$$4x+3 \geq 0 \Rightarrow x \geq \frac{-3}{4}$$

$$1+x^3 > 0 \Rightarrow x > -1$$

$$2x - \sqrt{4x+3} \neq 0 \Rightarrow x \neq \frac{3}{2} \land x \neq \frac{-1}{2}$$

I did the intersection of the entire domain and I get

$$x \in [0,  \frac{3}{2}) \cup (\frac{3}{2},+ \infty) $$

After this I solved $\log(1+x^3) \geq 0 \Rightarrow x \geq 0$ and after i solved 2x - sqrt(4x+3) > 0 with the system 1) 4x + 3 >= 0 , 2) 2x > 0 , 3) 4x+3 < 4x^2

1. => x >= -3/4
2. => x > 0
3. => (-∞, -1/2) U (3/2, +∞)

I did the intersection of this system and the result is x ∈ (3/2, +∞)

After verifying the domain, my solution is  x ∈ (3/2, +∞).

I saw on wolfram alpha if my solution was correct but its not.
It should be x ∈ [-3/4,0] U (3/2 , +∞).

Comment: Here's a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: That's not an inequality! It's just an expression.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to find the domain of your expression. That does require solving some inequalities, but you should say you seek the domain, rather than "solve inequality" because the whole thing is not an inequality.

Comment: OP: Are you trying to establish that the left-hand expression is non-negative whenever it is defined (i.e., when $4x+3 \geq 0$)? Or just, as others have mentioned, to identify the values of $x$ for which it is non-negative? If neither, can you clarify?

Comment: Make a sign table...

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
&&-1&&-\frac34&&-\frac12&&0&&\frac32&\\\hline
\log(1+x^3)&X&X&-&-&-&-&-&0&+&+&+\\\hline
2x-\sqrt{4x+3}&X&X&X&-&-&-&-&-&-&0&+\\\hline
f(x)&X&X&X&+&+&+&+&0&-&X&+\\\hline
\end{array}$$
From the sign table above the domain of $\sqrt{f(x)}=\sqrt{\frac{\log(1+x^3)}{2x-\sqrt{4x+3}}}$ is
$$D=[-\tfrac34,0]\cup(\tfrac32,\infty)$$